# iframe crawling & redirecting

Tags: javascript, iframe, indexing, web-crawler

I use some of pages of my website as **IFRAME**. My question is:

I want Google to crawl IFRAME contents **but** when the IFRAME url is typed in browser directly in browser or when a visitor clicks on the IFRAME url in search results, I want the visitor to be redirected to main page of my website.

Is it possible? If it is possible, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, just use this :

```
window.top.location.href = link;
```

Window.top will acces top the main page ;) But do you have acces to the iframe ?